# ci" or ci' doesn't work in vim key bindings for zsh command line editing

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, normal-mode

I have vim keybindings enabled for command line editing by `bindkey -v`. When I am trying to use ci", ci', di" or di' it doesn't work.

For example: If I have a command `echo "hello" 'world'` and when I have the cursor on h and I press ci", it just sound a bip and doesn't do anything.

In command line editing other vim commands involving text objects like ciw, daw, cis etc. works fine.

If I open files in vim offcourse everything works including ci" and ci'.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: `zsh` and `readline` are not Vim and their behavior is different. Unfortunately this forum is not dedicated to vi like question about `zsh` (see [Should questions about bash's vi mode be on-topic?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/57/23502) or [What is considered to be vi?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/37/23502)) :-|

Comment: Good to know. Anyway, welcome vi.SX @gman

Comment: It looks like this can be enabled with [select-quoted](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Functions/Zle/select-quoted), which should be bundled in zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vi key binding provide a subset of [legacy/POSIX vi](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) editing features. All of the line editing libraries (with ability to select vi/emacs key-binding —e.g. [GNU readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-vi-Mode.html), [zle](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html), [BSD libedit/editline](https://man.netbsd.org/editline.7), [haskeline](https://github.com/judah/haskeline/wiki/KeyBindings), etc.) have some limitations and are not (nor will be) a full Vi.

Comment: zsh doesn't use readline.

Comment: I never said that, but my answer still apply: even [zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html) doesn't have all legacy features and isn't meant to be a full vi either.

Comment: `I never said that`: well, you linked to the readline documentation.

Comment: readline as an example (i often face), but my main purpose is in the first sentence: they (shells and line editing libraries in general) implement only a part of official know vi commands and that's ok.

Comment: Answer edited, does it sweet you Martin? Also keep in mind that one cannot list all possible libs, but the idea is that I don't know any exception.

Comment: FWIW, readline and friends provide a "vi mode" anyway, not a "Vim mode". Vi didn't have text objects so there is no reason to expect a "vi mode" to have a Vim feature. Interestingly, some of them use vim-isms in their documentation ("insert mode", "operator-pending mode", etc.), which may hint at what their maintainers are actually looking at when working on the feature, but "vi mode" is still clearly labelled that way.

Comment: No one asked to "list all possible libraries". The question is about zsh, not readline or haskeline, or anything else. This question is off-topic here so it doesn't matter that much, but I'm reasonably sure `ci"` can be made to work with zsh without too much effort (maybe also readline? I'm less familiar with it). Actually, looking in to it [the feature is bundled with zle, and just needs to be enabled](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Functions/Zle/select-quoted). So yes, I'd say that linking to the correct documentation does matter.

Comment: I didn't read that the question was about zsh. Sorry for not having the same understanding as you.

Comment: It has "zsh" in the question title, so that's why I assumed it's a zsh question. It's not mentioned in the body though, and it's sometimes easy to miss if something is mentioned only in the title (I've done that anyway).

Comment: Oh my bad, you're right: I've missed Zsh mention in the title :( Many thanks for pointing that out @MartinTournoij (I realy need some rest...) I even though, because of `bindkey -v` that OP is a Tcsh user (when I gave Zsh a try, i didn't play with that command so forgot it doesn't go `set -o vi`) Anyway thanks for making me correct my answer.

Comment: @romainl I think most people use Vim nowadays and then adopt its documentation concepts. I also think POSIX call it "vi mode" because it's a modal editing with compatibility to standard visual and command modes for features that may exist. And it's good if inner ops are available with Zsh as Martin pointed out. However it's about one line editing, so absence of some movements (paragraphs and sections for example) makes sens imho. Something I missed sometime was `f`/`F`/`,`/`;` :D

Comment: Both `set -o vi` and `bindkey -v` work actually; AFAIK they're identical. zsh copied quite a few ideas and concepts from (t)csh. Anyway, I should have explicitly mentioned in my first comment that this question is about zsh, instead of just the short "zsh doesn't use readline" and/or have realized we were talking past each other after the first reply; would have saved both of us some time and frustration. Sorry about that.